# Cannot get @Ajax.ActionLink to work in a partial view, get "Cannot resolve" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, C#, Razor.

I have successfully got the Ajax.ActionLink working from my main page which contains a table and records with each containing a link. The Ajax.ActionLink "replaces" the record in all  cells within the  element. I use a partial view to do this replacing in:

```
<td>col1</td><td>col2</td>
```

However col1 should retain the Ajax.Actionlink as it will be required again, so my partial view should be:

```
<td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",...)</td><td>col2</td>
```

But I get a

> "cannot resolve symbol ActionLink"

error.

Am I missing a reference in the partial view. I did try System.Web.MVC.Ajax, but this failed.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT1:

Seems no issue with:

```
@Html.ActionLink(...)
```

EDIT2:

Full ActionLink code:

```
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
                                 "AjaxDelete",
                                 "Order",
                                 new {id = ViewBag.id},
                                 new AjaxOptions {
                    UpdateTargetId = ViewBag.rowname,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET"
                                 });
```

Comment: Can you show the additional parameters, rather than `...` as that is the most likely cause (incorrect overload matching)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just added the code as EDIT2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The compiler cannot create an anonymous type from a dynamic property as it has no idea what type it is.

Add an `(int)` cast to `ViewBag.id` to make the anonymous field strongly typed.

Also do the same same for `Viewbag.rowname` (string I assume?)

### e.g.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
               "AjaxDelete",
               "Order",
               new {id = (int)ViewBag.id},
               new AjaxOptions {
               UpdateTargetId = (string)ViewBag.rowname,
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               HttpMethod = "GET"
               });
```

Comment: Well that was weird. It does seemed to have fixed it. Also I am using Resharper and it highlighted "ActionLink" in red, and offered reference type solutions which seemed to cause my VS2012 to hang. So a big thank you. This had me very confused.

Comment: Out of interest, is this the correct approach to ensuring the Ajax link is retained within the replaced HTML? Thanks

Comment: That is the correct way (only way aside from client-side code?) to insert parameters into an Ajax.ActionLink link.

Comment: Thank. BTW, I love your profile..... Just picturing a retirement home full of coders on laptops !!!

Comment: Glad you like it. It is a concern for me in the next decade or so :)

Comment: Same for me, but due to age inflation there is another 40 years before it becomes relevant :)

Comment: Hmmmm..... Thanks again. You are a true example to the SO community. Pleasure meeting you.