# Image upload : No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi every one I am trying to create an mvc application that allows the user to upload photos but I am getting this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

The program complies but i am not sure what the issue is. I am also getting an red underline error on this line:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })"
```

> "Cannot covert type int id to system.web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions"

It does not stop the program from running, but I am not sure what the issue with this is as it is not anonymous type

Index

```
 @model IEnumerable<Myprogram.Models.Image> 
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Create

```
@model Myprogram.Models.Image
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Image", null, FormMethod.Post,
                                          new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Image</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image"
                   type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Model

```
namespace Myprogram.Models
{
    public partial class Image
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Home Controller

```
 public class EFDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Image> Image { get; set; }
        }


        public interface IRepository
        {

            IEnumerable<Image> images { get; }
            void Create(Image images);

        }
        private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();
        private IRepository repository;
        public HomeController(IRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Image> images
        {
            get { return db.Image; }
        }
        public ViewResult Create()
        {
            return View(repository.images);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Image img, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Img/")
                                                          + file.FileName);
                    img.ImagePath = file.FileName;
                }
                db.Image.Add(img);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(img);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using dependency injection to pass the `IRepository` to the `HomeController?` If so, can you show the code where you set that up, and if not, how are you expecting it to be injected?

Comment: And regarding the `ActionLink`, you're [using the wrong overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Regarding your 2nd issue, i.e. for `ajax ActionLink`, **[this could be the possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24826527/2065039)**